# Check for page loading (Python)

Tags: python, browser

In Python, is there any way that I can find out if a browser window that I've opened has loaded completely or not, maybe using a package (for instance, `webbrowser`)? Once it's loaded completely I want to take a screenshot of it and save it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using e.g. [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/download/); I'm not sure if it's what you want, though. See this [short guide](http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2009/09/selenium-rc-with-python-in-30-seconds.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import selenium

sel = selenium('localhost', 4444, '*firefox', 'http://www.google.com/')
sel.start()
sel.open('/')
sel.wait_for_page_to_load(10000)
sel.stop()
```

You could also use COM hooks to control IE (ugh):

```
import win32com.client
import time

ie = win32com.client.Dispatch( "InternetExplorer.Application" )
ie.Navigate( <some URL> )
time.sleep( 1 )
print( ie.Busy )
```

There's a module that wraps all the COM functionality: [`IEC.py`](http://www.mayukhbose.com/python/IEC/index.php).

Comment: What does "sel.wait_for_page_to_load(10000)" actually mean? Would it mean I have to wait out 10000 seconds or is it like the maximum time limit?

Comment: I liked your second suggestion, because then I wouldn't need to install anything new.The only problem being - except for the first time I'd get this error - "pywintypes.com_error: (-2147023174, 'The RPC server is unavailable.', None, None)"

Comment: @fixxxer: it's a timeout. The selenium docs will tell you more. I would try Googling the RPC server error, I think you need to start some services. Can you access the page in IE normally?

Comment: yes, I'm able to open the page in IE normally.I wouldn't have commented the RPC problem without Googling it. :)
 thx

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking you can't do that with python. However, using Javascript you can wait for the "onload" event and send an ajax request to your python backend.
With [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) it should be something like.

```
//callback for the onload
jQuery(document)
        .ready(function() {

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "thePythonScript.py",
   data: "name=Daniel&location=Somewhere",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });

});
```

Comment: I do not want to use anything else than Python packages. Is there anyway around this problem with win32api?
thanks for the help.

Comment: If the browser is running in a different machine, then JS is your only option. Why you don't want to use JS for this ?

Comment: primarily because I havn't used JS ever and I want to learn more about Python's bells and whistles than that of JS right now.

Comment: understood, you have a more academic motivation. Good luck!