# Selenium Python: Need to get screenshot of an inactive window and display

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to take a screenshot of a portion of a website. 
I used the script in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563350/take-a-screenshot-of-open-website-in-python-script) .

But the problem is, it is taking the screenshot of the current window. But I would like to take a screenshot of the browser window opened through selenium(which would not be active).

The website I would like to take a screenshot of is [this](http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/computers-software/techmahindra/TM4). I need the element "content_full" so that I can display the content as it is using my script. This is not an image. So I am unable to use any selenium scripts.