# open a browser page and take screenshot every n hour in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, screenshot

I want to open a web page then take a screenshot every 2 hours via python.
here is my code to open a page at every 2 hour interval

```
import time
import webbrowser
total_breaks = 12
break_count = 0

while(break_count < total_breaks):
    time.sleep(7200)
    webbrowser.open("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/2")
    break_count = break_count + 1
```

i followed [Take a screenshot of open website in python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563350/take-a-screenshot-of-open-website-in-python-script) but didn't get any success 
I am using python 3.5 . I got a module wxpython but it supportts only 2.x . So is there way to take a screen shot every 2 hours using python 3

Comment: Have you tried selenium? Also, instead of doing a `time.sleep(7200)`, write a cronjob to run every 2 hours.

Comment: FWIW, there are probably better / more powerful ways to get the information that you _really_ want than by taking screenshots.

Comment: if you have wxpython for Python 2.x then install Python 2.x

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi i am using windows

Comment: @ishaan Thhanks for the info. I am  looking at selenium now ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you have to with Selenium to get started.

1. Install Selenium using pip by `pip install selenium` in the command prompt.

---

2. Make sure you have the python path in your environment variables.

---

3. Run this script by changing the email and the password below.

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(30)
browser.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier')
email = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Email"]')
email.clear()
email.send_keys("email@gmail.com")  # change email
email.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
password = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Passwd"]')
password.clear()
password.send_keys("password")  # Change Password
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(10)
browser.save_screenshot('screen_shot.png')
browser.close()
```

4. And finally you can run `schtask` on the saved python file from the command prompt. 
   `schtask` is the `CRON` equivalent on windows.

---

```
schtasks /Create /SC MINUTE /MO  120 /TN screenshot /TR "PATH_TO_PYTHON_FILE\FILE.py"
```