# Automated Screenshot with Python / Crontab / Selenium / Time on mac

Tags: python, selenium, cron, mozilla

I have pulled a few things from other answers today (this for instance: [open a browser page and take screenshot every n hour in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961910/open-a-browser-page-and-take-screenshot-every-n-hour-in-python-3/68189559#68189559))

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(30)
browser.get('https://weather.com/en-AU/weather/today/l/ASXX0023:1:AS?Goto=Redirected')
time.sleep(10)
browser.save_screenshot('screen_shot.png')
browser.close()
```

this solution is working perfectly except I'm not sure how to execute in crontab.

i tried this after typing crontab -e then:

```
*/30 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /Users/path/script.py >> /path/screenshot.png
```

and it opens the firefox window, but the screenshot is Zero Bytes.. so it's close to what I want, but not quite there.

I tried a few other ways too - with script.sh - though I'm not to sure how to get that working either.

Also - it'd be good to add the time and date to the screenshot, so any help there is a blessing.

could you offer any guidance? Thanks!

Comment: The shell redirection `>> /path/screenshot.png` looks wrong but harmless. I'm guessing you are doing something even more bewildering in your real code. Probably redirect the script's output (and standard error) to a log file instead.

Comment: The `DISPLAY=:0` looks wrong for a Mac, or are you really running X11? Again, it should be harmless _per se,_ but betrays a poor understanding of the pieces you have cobbled together.

Comment: Yep - I'm a few weeks into python and this is my first attempt at cron - not even sure what X11 is, but DISPLAY=:0 was recommended on most other things, and actually got it working. The code I'm using is exactly the code above, unfortunately.

Comment: X11 is a GUI system common on Linux and Unix system, but Macs use their own and quite distinct framework, called Darwin.

Comment: `/Users/name/code/screenshot.png` is the crontab path I'm using. there was no mention of Darwin on any previous sites - I'll look into it.

Comment: Probably the sites you have explored explain how to do this on Linux, which requires setting up an X11 server if you don't already have one, and give `cron` access to the currently open display. There are many reasons that's complicated, but if you are on a Mac and are certain to be logged into the GUI at all times, you don't need to worry about those complications.

Comment: Does `/Users/name/code` exist and is it writable by the user whose `cron` job this is? Your `cron` job will write to a file in your home directory, though. Probably you are simply examining the wrong file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cron` job will start in your home directory, and writes the screenshot to the current directory.

The `cron` job you have will *also* write the standard output from Python to a misleadingly named PNG file which will probably be empty. Probably this is the file you have been examining.

*Probably* restructure to switch to a different directory (or modify the Python script to read an output file name as its command-line argument) and write the script's output to a differently named file, also then including standard error.  Furthermore, the `DISPLAY` variable does nothing useful on a Mac, so probably drop it.

```
*/30 * * * * cd code; /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /Users/path/script.py >> screenshot_$(date +\%F).log 2>&1
```

This also illustrates how to create a new log file for each separate date.  The requirement to backslash the percent sign in `crontab` is a common trip-up.

If instead, or as well, you would like the Python script to generate a unique file name for each invocation, try something like

```
from datetime import datetime

... 
browser.save_screenshot(
    'screen_shot_' + datetime.now().strftime('%F_%T') + '.png')
```

This will generate a file like `screen_shot_2021-06-30_10:26:26.png`; maybe play around with the [argument to `strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) if you would like a different date or time format.